# C# Create Excell Cell address from row and column number without Interop dll

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I am reading Excel file into DataTable without Excel interop library.
From DataTable I need to find out some value and its address relative to excel.

Example I found my value in dt.Rows[7].ItemArray[1].ToString(), so its address interms of excel should be "B8".

Like that I need to convert DataTable cell address to Excel cell address.

Here is my code that is used to read Excel file.

```
public DataTable getExcelSheet(string filePath, string sheetName)
    {
        var ds = new DataSet();
        var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\""; ;
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            var sheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "] ";

                var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

This function is to find out value from datatable

```
public String getTablePosition(DataTable dataTable, String value)
        {
            string cell = "";
            for (int rows = 0; rows < (dataTable.Rows.Count < 100 ? dataTable.Rows.Count : 100); rows++)
            {
                for (int cols = 1; cols < (dataTable.Columns.Count < 100 ? dataTable.Columns.Count : 100); cols++)
                {
                    if (dataTable.Rows[rows].ItemArray[cols].ToString() == value)
                    {
                        return ""  //here cell I need cell address like B8 or CQ15
                    }
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Can anyone help me in this ? I need to do this without using Excel interop library.

Comment: What do you want to do? Iterate through a column? Or select a cell based on the value?

Comment: see the function getTablePosition(), that will find out value from data table, when cell is matched i wants its address in form of Excel.
Example i found value at dt.Rows[7].ItemArray[1].ToString() than it should return its address as B8.

Comment: Update your query `SELECT * FROM [MySheet$A1:C20]`. Now you know the range so you can compute the column and row indexes depending if headers are enabled or disabled

Comment: No, row and column range can be extended. I need to find out cell address based on column and row number

Comment: You cannot achieve what you want with the approach you are taking. If you dont want to use Interop, there are other alternatives like OpenXML, EEPlus

Answer (score -1):

I created function that creates cell address based on column and row number.

```
     string[] Columns = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };

 public String getExcelAddress(int row, int column)
        {
            string cellAddress = "";
            cellAddress = ((column / 26) - 1 >= 1 ? Columns[(column / 26) - 1] : "") + Columns[column % 26] + (row + 1);
            return cellAddress;
        }

        public String getTablePosition(DataTable dataTable, String value)
        {
            for (int rows = 0; rows < (dataTable.Rows.Count < 100 ? dataTable.Rows.Count : 100); rows++)
            {
                for (int cols = 1; cols < (dataTable.Columns.Count < 100 ? dataTable.Columns.Count : 100); cols++)
                {
                    if (dataTable.Rows[rows].ItemArray[cols].ToString().Trim() == value.Trim())
                    {
                        return getExcelAddress(rows, cols);
                    }
                }
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: Will give wrong references if Column A or any preceding columns are empty. Will also give wrong references if `HDR=Yes` and/or first few rows are blank.

Comment: what is HDR=Yes ?

Comment: You can read about [Excel connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)